# Is RTMP supported in BlazeDS yet?

Tags: blazeds, rtmp

Since Adobe opened the RTMP specification to the community, does it mean that RTMP will be supported by BlazeDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know RTMP is not there yet :(
But you can try messaging with StreamingAMF or pooling :)

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_use_BlazeDS_Messaging-7765.html

Comment: Another option is Red5 and maybe GraniteDS has RTMP now.

Comment: Not yet, and they have only long polling in order to implement the data push (no streaming).

Comment: I don't think GraniteDS has RTMP yet. They do have Comet-like data push implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MuleRTMP (http://code.google.com/p/mulertmp/) to adapt Red5's RTMP Handler as Endpoints into BlazeDS.